# Can't bind to 'menuList' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement the code mentioned in the link below

```
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/recursive-tree-view-using-angular-2-and-typescript-till-nth-level-depth/
```

I am struck in the middle with the following log.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'menuList' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'.
1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component and it has 'menuList' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<tree-view [ERROR ->][menuList]="menuList"></tree-view>"): ng:///AppModuleShared/TreeViewComponent.html@0:11
'tree-view' is not a known element:
1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<tree-view [menuList]="menuList"></tree-view>"): ng:///AppModuleShared/TreeViewComponent.html@0:0
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'menuList' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'.
1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component and it has 'menuList' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<tree-view [ERROR ->][menuList]="menuList"></tree-view>"): ng:///AppModuleShared/TreeViewComponent.html@0:11
'tree-view' is not a known element:
1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<tree-view [menuList]="menuList"></tree-view>"): ng:///AppModuleShared/TreeViewComponent.html@0:0
```

**EDIT**

Below is the code that I have implemented for TreeViewComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeView } from './tree-view.directive';
import { ProjectRoleService } from './project-role.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'tree-view-menu',
    template: '<tree-view [menuList]="menuList"></tree-view>',
    styleUrls: ['./tree-view.css']
})
export class TreeViewComponent {
    public roleName: string = 'Admin';
    menuList: any;
    constructor(private _projectService: ProjectRoleService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.roleName = "Admin";
        this._projectService.getMenuDetails(this.roleName).then((res: any) => {
            this.menuList = res;
        }, (error) => {
            throw new Error('This request has failed ' + Response.error);
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the code for app.shared.module.ts. Please find it below. I have removed few imports which are very common.

```
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { TreeViewMenuComponent } from './components/treeview/tree-view-menu.component';
import { TreeView } from './components/treeview/tree-view.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        TreeViewMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'tree-view-menu', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'tree-view-menu', component: TreeViewMenuComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'tree-view-menu' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

Is there any clue for this?

Comment: post your code of treeview

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: Your component should be TreeViewMenuComponent, not TreeViewComponent

Comment: Post module code where you inject `TreeViewComponent` inside ngModule and inject `schemes: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`  in ngModule.

Comment: I am using Angular 4 for this. Where can I implement this.

Comment: post your sharedmodule.ts

Comment: Added app.shared.module.ts

Comment: is this the only module you have?

Comment: I have injected schemes with CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA and the error is gone.